# In F# is it possible to create a pattern that will match multiple cases of a discriminate union?

Tags: .net, f#, pattern-matching

Lets say I have a discriminated union like this:

```
type Example = 
   |Foo of string
   |Bar of int
   |Baz of int
   |Qux of int
   |NoValue
```

Is there any concise way to complete the following function without specifying all the remaining cases

```
let doIt (ex:Example) = 
    match ex with
    | Foo(_) -> 0
    | NoValue -> -1
```

Such that the pattern will generically handle the remaining similarly structured union cases the same way. In the example code, it would mean a single case statement for Bar,Baz, and Qux that would behave like the following.

```
    | Bar(i) -> i
```

I didn't see anything in the language reference that would allow this type of matching but I'm curious if it's possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not quite as concise as you want, but you can do something like this using the [OR pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx):

```
let doIt (ex:Example) =
    match ex with
    | Foo(_) -> 0
    | NoValue -> -1
    | Bar(i) | Baz(i) | Qux(i) -> i;;
```

It does, however, eliminate the duplication of all of the (possibly) complex portion of that case.

For the sake of further illustration, you can also do this even if your cases don't match exactly like so:

```
type Example =
  | Foo of string
  | Bar of int * int
  | Baz of int
  | Qux of int
  | NoValue

let doIt (ex:Example) =
    match ex with
    | Foo _ -> 0
    | NoValue -> -1
    | Bar(i,_) | Baz i | Qux i -> i
```

Answer (score 11):

You can also change the view of discriminated unions using [Active Patterns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233248.aspx):

```
let (|SingleInt|_|) = function
   | Foo _ -> None
   | NoValue -> None
   | Bar i | Baz i | Qux i -> Some i

let doIt ex = 
    match ex with
    | SingleInt i -> i
    | Foo _ -> 0
    | NoValue -> -1
```

But if three cases should be handled in the same way repetitively, you should consider to refactor your DUs:

```
type IntCase = | Bar | Baz | Qux

type Example = 
   | Foo of string
   | SingleInt of int * IntCase
   | NoValue

let doIt ex = 
    match ex with
    | SingleInt(i, _) -> i
    | Foo _ -> 0
    | NoValue -> -1
```

Comment: I agree in general with your refactor if the int cases are going to commonly be used in a repetitive way. I accepted the other because in this particular use case, Bar,Baz,Qux are generally used discretely, but in one particular case, need to be handled generically.

Comment: Fair point. That particular case is called [OR pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547125.aspx) if you wonder.

Comment: Combining these answers would be excellent, they were both really useful.